# How does Python interpret arguments in class definition?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to understand the source code of Beautifulsoup.

The first several lines of its source code is:

```
class Beautifulsoup(Tag):
    def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
    parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, exclude_encodings=None,
    **kwargs):
        ...
```

There is only one argument called "Tag" on the first line, but many more in the **init** function. On the other hand, I know we usually use beautifulsoup in somehow this way:

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
bsobj = Beautifulsoup(text, parser)
```

1. What is that "Tag" argument in the class definition?

Update: 
As said in @BusyAnt @Vatine 's answer, Tag is not an argument but the super class of Beautifulsoup. And I found Tag's class definition in another file:

```
class Tag(PageElement):

"""Represents a found HTML tag with its attributes and contents."""

def __init__(self, parser=None, builder=None, name=None, namespace=None,
             prefix=None, attrs=None, parent=None, previous=None):
    "Basic constructor."
```

And finally PageElement is also a class defined in the same file:

```
class PageElement(object):
"""Contains the navigational information for some part of the page
(either a tag or a piece of text)"""
```

Whooo!

2. Which argument in the **init** correspond to text and parser in actual usage?

Comment: Are you referring to `class Beatifulsoup(Tag)` ? Or are you asking how function parameters work in python?

Comment: its same as normal function's arguments, except first self is refer to class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Tag` is the class that `BeautifoulSoup` inherits from. It's not an argument. Please [take a look at this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php) to learn more.
2. As for the arguments in `__init__`: *`self`* refers to the instance of the class that will be created. The other arguments are written with default values, which means that they will take this value if not specified when you call the method. And as you did specify two arguments with no names in your example, the positional order will be used, that is to say `markers=text` and `features=parser`. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/class-python) would be a good way to start learning about it.

---

I'm not willing to sound harsh, but it *might* not be the best idea to start wandering in this source code while you are not familiar with the concepts of classes, objects, and some other basic stuff in Python.

Comment: I will take some time to read materials you recommended. thx!

Comment: You have a good state of mind. You'll be able to find plenty of simple examples about this and other things on the Internet, or even here, on [StackOverflow Dowumentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics)

Answer (score 1):

The line `class BeautifulSoup(Tag):` means "please start defining a class named BeautifulSoup, inheriting from the class Tag".

The line(s) `def __init__(self, markup="", features=None...` mean "let the class's constructor take the arguments ...", with the very first one being the instance the constructor method is invoked on (it's not necessary to call this `self`, but it is **strongly** recommended). The rest of the arguments work like that of a normal function.

In the specific invocation you've shown, `markup` will get the value of `text` and `features` that of `parser` (you're not using any keywords, so they'll be positional, with most of them having default values).